# Same address is getting stored in the head of a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to implement hash tables in C++. So for this, I have created an array of linked lists. But I am having issues with maintaining the head of each list.

And I have a linked_list named **`ContactList`** and the array of the list is defined in another class called **`PhoneBook`**:

```
class ContactList {            
    public:
    Contact *head;
    void AddName(Contact *);
};


class PhoneBook {
    public:
    ContactList arr[100000];
};
```

which is supposed to contain nodes defined in the following manner:

```
struct Contact {
    int phone;
    string name;
    Contact *next;
};
```

the `AddName` function is supposed to go through the whole list to find a node with the same number and if it finds that node, it simply modifies the `node.name`, otherwise it adds it to the end of the list. I wrote the following code to carry this out:

```
void ContactList::AddName(Contact *contact){
    bool flag = 0;
    Contact *node = head;
    if(node == NULL){
        head = contact;
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

A call to function `AddName` goes like this:

```
Contact contact{queries[i].number, queries[i].name};
phonebook.arr[k].AddName(&contact);
```

But the problem is that at every call the address of argument `contact` is the same and therefore the same address is stored in the head of every list at each index. How do I change the call to allocate new memory? Or should I change something inside my `AddNew` function?

Edit: I figured out I was not allocating new memory, so I looked for a solution and made the following changes:

```
void ContactList::AddName(Contact contact){
    bool flag = 0;
    struct Contact *new_node = (struct Contact *) malloc(sizeof(struct Contact));
    new_node->phone = contact.phone;
    new_node->name = contact.name;
    if(head == NULL){
        head = new_node;
        return;
    }
```

But now I am getting a Segmentation Error in the following line:

```
new_node->name = contact.name;
```

Comment: If you say `phonebook.arr[k].AddName(&contact);`, you are adding `contact`'s address to the list. You need to add a copy instead. Any in any case, it seems that the last code snipped was included in some loop, which is dangerous as you would be passing the address of a local/temporary variable.

Comment: @molbdnilo most probably [hashing with chaining](https://www.opendatastructures.org/ods-cpp/5_1_Hashing_with_Chaining.html)

Comment: @andreee I should have read the first sentence...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are creating a stack variable and then adding its address in the list. Then maybe you change the values and add it again.

To  achieve your desired behavior you must create new instances at each entry. For this you can use `new` to create different contacts.

```
  Contact* contact = new Contact;
```

Even better will be to use a smart pointers in order to manage the memory and ensure no memory leaks.

```
std::unique_ptr<Contact> contact = std::make_unique<Contact>();
```